# Jquery mobile - Why there is ajax calling when I click button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, smarty

I have a problem with my Jquery mobile code. When I hit button it redirects me to another page but when I check Firebug console there is ajax calling: GET http://www.example.com/cz/cs/7_kontakty.html 200 OK 162ms .

Code:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
// turn off Ajax (no compability with jQuery functions)
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
   $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
{/literal}
<div class="menu-top" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;" >
  <a class="globe" href="http://www.example.com/{$country}/{$lang}/7_kontakty.html?do=mob_countries" data-role="button" data-inline="true"><img width="37px" src="/css/globe_menu.png" alt="globe" /></a>
  <a class="message" href="http://www.example.com/{$country}/{$lang}/7_kontakty.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true"><img width="37px" src="http://www.example.com/css/message.png" alt="message" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon There is no click function on that element

Comment: So you are saying the behavior is correct but there is an undesired request meanwhile?

Comment: @clapas There is no my Jquery function for class globe or message. After I click that button I am redirected to that page with ajax. I don't know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn AJAX navigation off in jQuery mobile, you need to make sure that you set your `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled` property to false on the prototype *before* you load in jQuery Mobile.

In other words, what you need to do is something like the following:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="//[cdn or your local path to jQuery goes here]" />
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function() { $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; });
</script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="//[cdn or your local path to jQuery Mobile goes here]" />
```

This works because you are changing the prototype directly (think of it like setting a variable), which does not require the library to be loaded. When initialized, the library will look for the settings on the `$.mobile` prototype and will use those to determine whether or not to turn AJAX navigation on.

If you would like to change more settings, as I did on my personal site, you can do something like the following:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function() { $.extend( $.mobile, { ajaxEnabled: !1, defaultPageTransition: "none" }) });
```

Because the performance hit is so minimal to load in one extra JS file, I prefer to put my mobile settings in a separate file, just to keep things neat when browsing the source (personal preference). If you want to see the working example of disabling the AJAX navigation, you can look at the source code for [my personal site](http://zacharykniebel.com).

Comment: Yes I did. Same effect. {literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
// turn off Ajax (no compability with jQuery functions)
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
{/literal}
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

Comment: Review my updates. Make sure that you are doing things in the following order: (1) Load jQuery, but not jQuery Mobile; (2) Set your `ajaxEnabled` setting for jQuery Mobile; (3) Load in jQuery Mobile

Comment: It should be valid ? <link href="/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/stylex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>{literal}<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("mobileinit", function() { $.extend( $.mobile, { ajaxEnabled: !1, defaultPageTransition: "none" }) }
</script>{/literal}{literal}<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){

Comment: No, that is incorrect. You are loading jQuery Mobile in before you set `ajaxEnabled = false`. You need to set the variable *before* loading jQuery mobile.

Comment: Go to [my personal site](http://zacharykniebel.com), right-click and click *view source*. At the top, you will see where I load in my resources, and there will be one called "mobile-settings.min.js". That is where I am setting `ajaxEnabled=false`. Note where I am loading in jQuery Core and where I load in jQuery mobile. Feel free to copy my set-up, if you wish.

Comment: Thank you very much. +1 for U